# I'm not sure if number in mov is hex or decimal

Tags: assembly, numbers, hex, decimal, mov

I have exercise from assembler where i need to tell what will be in A on end of program

```
start: mov A, 5d //I know that is address of memory
mov A, #5d      //Not sure what it is
inc A          //increase A by 1
inc A         //same
```

I'm not sure if i should take 5D from `mov A, #5d`as hex number or decimal number 5. I hope someone will help me with this.

Comment: What type of assembly are we talking about here? 8086?

Comment: If i only knew. We worked with it on microcontroller 8051/52 if it help somehow

Comment: I guess it's 8051, but we can't help you unless you specify the exact assembler used. I vote for hex, since if it were decimal it would just be `5` and `5` is the same in hex and decimal so you wouldn't even bother spelling out the `d`. The `#` denotes immediate.

Comment: Is this AVR assembler?

Comment: Just assemble that source, then disassemble it (with hexdump) and see what the immediate byte is.  i.e. whether it's `0x5d` or `0x05`.

Comment: @Jester phrases like "doesn't make sense" don't apply to teachers :) mine always used "d" for decimals, even for 0d and 1d. I vote for decimal 5. 5d hex would've been 0x5d or 5dh